# How to exclude a single field from firing the onchange event registered at a whole form (vanilla JS)?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `form` with `onchange` event registered like this:

```
<form onchange="myEventFunction();">
    <select name="select1">options...</select>
    <select name="select2">options...</select>
    <select name="select3">options...</select>
</form>
```

This works pefectly fine, the event gets triggered when one changes any select field.

But how can I configure one of the selects to *not* trigger the onchange event? Or, alternatively, how do I check for the triggering element in `myEventFunction()` to do an early return then?

Use case: Changing the form should reload search results via `XmlHttpRequest` (this works perfectly fine). But one of the fields is just to change a different field's options and should not trigger the "submit". My real-world form is much bigger than this example, so registering an `onchange` on every single field except one is only the very last "brute-force" solution for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the event argument and check against the `event.target`'s `name` property:

```js
function myEventFunction(event) {
  if (event.target.name == "select2") {
    event.preventDefault();
  } else {
    console.log('changed');
  }
}
```

```html
<form onchange="myEventFunction(event)">
  <select name="select1">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
  </select>
  <select name="select2">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
  </select>
  <select name="select3">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a change event listener to the form and check for the element that triggered the event.

Something like this:

```js
document.querySelector('form')
.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.name); //returns the name of the element that triggered the event
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option given to other answers is to simply move the `onchange` attribute to your selects.

```
<form>
    <select name="select1" onchange="myEventFunction();">options...</select>
    <select name="select2">options...</select>
    <select name="select3" onchange="myEventFunction();">options...</select>
</form>
```

I believe you will also make some modifications to the function code since [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_this.asp) will point to the `select` instead of `form`